# Spring Cloud + Feign + Nacos failed to req API:/nacos/v1/ns/instance

Tags: java, spring-cloud-feign, nacos

**Hello
I tried launching a Feign + SpringCloud Demo with Nacos as the configuration center,but Nacos started abnormally, please help me to check the problem, thank you very much！！！**

MY Exception Message: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to req API:/nacos/v1/ns/instance after all servers([127.0.0.1:8848]) tried: failed to req API:127.0.0.1:8848/nacos/v1/ns/instance. code:500 msg: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) at com.alibaba.nacos.client.naming.net.NamingProxy.reqAPI(NamingProxy.java:467) ~[nacos-client-1.1.4.jar:na] at com.alibaba.nacos.client.naming.net.NamingProxy.reqAPI(NamingProxy.java:389) ~[nacos-client-1.1.4.jar:na] at com.alibaba.nacos.client.naming.net.NamingProxy.registerService(NamingProxy.java:191) ~[nacos-client-1.1.4.jar:na] at com.alibaba.nacos.client.naming.NacosNamingService.registerInstance(NacosNamingService.java:207) ~[nacos-client-1.1.4.jar:na] at com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.registry.NacosServiceRegistry.register(NacosServiceRegistry.java:64) ~[spring-cloud-alibaba-nacos-discovery-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE] at org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.AbstractAutoServiceRegistration.register(AbstractAutoServiceRegistration.java:239) ~[spring-cloud-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]`

- My application.yaml

  `spring: application: name: demo-provider  cloud: nacos: discovery: server-addr: 127.0.0.1:8848 server: port: ${random.int[10000,19999]}`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy4FJ.png)

- My code:

  @RestController
  public class ProviderController {

  ```
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProviderController.class);

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private Integer serverPort;

    @GetMapping("/echo")
    public String echo(String name) throws InterruptedException {
        // 模拟执行 100ms 时长。方便后续我们测试请求超时
        Thread.sleep(100L);

        // 记录被调用的日志
        logger.info("[echo][被调用啦 name({})]", name);

        return serverPort + "-provider:" + name;
    }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with Nacos deployment and it is not available.
Please make sure your Nacos is available and you can enter the management page.

Comment: Hello,The startup failed because the local NACOS configuration file was not properly configured. I have successfully started NACOS and can call it normally.Thanks  for your help !

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the Nacos Server is started

> ps -ef | grep nacos

2. Check the port 8848

> lsof -i:8848

3. Check the Nacos log

> cat ~/nacos/logs/start.out